Looking for a novel about a chess player murdered by computer
The main plot is, more or less: A famous chess player is found dead after a contest. He used a brain injection device controlled by an AI to help him training. Some doubts are maybe the AI killed him, so the main characters went on a research. It turns out that the AI wasn't doing this on purpose: It gave the positive stimulation to the man's brain, not knowing that the man was having an intercourse. The combined stimulation was too much that the man got killed.
I do have some details, but they are in pieces: 1. During the research, they went on an island where the computer and brain experiments are conducted. And they encountered some danger. 2. There are many scientific narration in the novel, which I found very interesting. For example, there was a debate whether bio brains/computers or silicon chips will prevail in the future, pros and cons was discussed, including silicon chips are fast and accurate, while bio brains/computers, although unstable, has larger memories and higher calculation speed potentials. Also, on their way to the island, the narrative describes the woman flipping her hair, with pheromones, hormones, and other biochemical reactions aiding in persuading the reluctant boatman. Another example is that in the end, the main characters fell in love, and the woman invited the man to bed. The man said I don't sleep with ... in the first day (couldn't remember the exact reason). The woman was sad but the man returned just after midnight, saying it was already the second day. And the narration included how pubic hair reduces the impact, how body temperature goes up and sweat is produced, and I remember the words "He loves her, ...(scientific narrations)" and "She loves him, ...(scientific narrations)"
Some other information: 1. The main characters are not police. They are clever minds, probably from some sort of genius club, who are interested in this incident. 2. The boatman mentioned above turns out to be a bad guy, who is with the island owner. 3. The danger they encountered on the island includes imprisonment and forced brain surgery, and the solution includes cutting the electric wire of the computer. (not very sure about this one)

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember when you read this?  Was it a hardcover, paperback or e-book?  Can you describe the cover art?  Did it take place on Earth?  Was it set in a real-world city?  You also have a trailing sentence; can you [edit] in the missing words?

Thank you! I read this 7 years ago, in the high school library. It wasn't e-book, but I can't remember if it's a hardcover or paperback, neither can I remember the cover art. Yes, it took place on Earth, not sure if it's set in real cities. I edited the question, thank you for reminding me!

Ah, much like chess boxing, chess sexing is a dangerous sport!

Haha, clever one!

Reminds me of 2 things, (Neither of which is OP's story) 1st: Fred Saberhagen's "Octagon" (1981) a Novel, A computer plays a multi-player game, programmed to win. Realizes if other players die in real life, it gains an advantage, increasing the odds of winning. 2nd "Brainstorm" (1983) a movie, people use a device to record sensations from a person's brain on tape for others to experience, it also, unexpectedly, records their emotions. Someone records themselves during sex, someone else has a heart attack as he watches a loop of the "release". (He's over stimulated as it plays over & over)
